# Object Array For Loop

Tags: java, arrays, object, for-loop

```
public class Team {
    public int health;
    public int x;
    public int conflict;

}

public class Test extends Activity {
    Team enemy[] = new Team[50];
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            for(int i =0; i<enemy.length; i++){
            enemy[i].health = 0;
            enemy[i].x = -100;
            enemy[i].conflict = 0;
            }
        }
}
```

With the for loop my game crashes, without the for loop it run. What am I doing wrong? thanks for the help ahead of time!

Comment: -1 because some very simple debugging would have solved this one.

Answer (score 7):

When you create the array:

```
Team enemy[] = new Team[50];
```

all the entries are `null`. You need to initialize each element of the array in your loop:

```
for(int i =0; i<enemy.length; i++){
    enemy[i] = new Team(); // <-- added
    enemy[i].health = 0;
    enemy[i].x = -100;
    enemy[i].conflict = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to instantiate `enemy[i]`

Do the following instead

```
Team enemy[] = new Team[50];
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    for(int i =0; i<enemy.length; i++){
      enemy[i] = new Team();
      enemy[i].health = 0;
      enemy[i].x = -100;
      enemy[i].conflict = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new Team object each iteration of the loop

```
for(int i =0; i<enemy.length; i++){
        enemy[i] = new Team();
        enemy[i].health = 0;
        enemy[i].x = -100;
        enemy[i].conflict = 0;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you never initialized the elements of enemy.

```
enemy[i] = new Team();

enemy[i].health = 0;
enemy[i].x = -100;
enemy[i].conflict = 0;
```